# ¿Por qué recibo NullPointerException con arrays?

Tags: java, array, excepciones

Tengo este código pero me salta un `NullPointerException` y no sé cuál puede ser el fallo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String[] mensaje;
    public static String men;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Eliga una opcion [1-3]");
        System.out.println("Codificar mensaje");
        System.out.println("Decodificar mensaje");
        System.out.println("Salir");
        int opcion = sc.nextInt();
        if(opcion == 1){
            sc.nextLine(); //Limpio el buffer de entrada
            codificar();
        }else if(opcion == 2){
            sc.nextLine(); //Limpio el buffer de entrada
            decodificar();
        }else if(opcion == 3){
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }
    public static void codificar(){
        System.out.println("Introduzca el mesaje a codificar sin signos de puntuacion");
        int n = 0;
        while(n>-1){
            men = sc.nextLine().toString(); //Guardo cada palabra del String en la variable en y si quito .toString() el problema sigue
            try{
                mensaje[n] = men; //Asigno cada palabra a un valor del array
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Aqui me salta NullPointerException
            }
            System.out.println(mensaje[n]);
                //Y aquí también me salta
            n++;
        }

    }
    public static void decodificar(){

    }
}
```

Comment: No has *inicializado* la variable `mensaje`. - Creo que sería de gran ayuda si añadieras cuál es el propósito del programa o qué es lo que debe hacer.

Comment: También sería de ayuda si incluyeras en qué línea de código es donde te da el error, así como el mensaje de error completo. Eso ahorraría mucho tiempo a la hora de mirar el código.

Comment: Dentro del bucle while , cuando dices antes que ," no debe tener signo de puntuación el mensaje a codificar" , ¿no sería conveniente que crearas una excepción y un método privado por si el mensaje tiene signos de puntuación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como bien dice Simon, sale un ´NullPointerException´ cuando intentas usar un objeto, en tu caso `mensaje`(de tipo `Array`), sin antes haberlo inicializado. Para usar variables podes verlo como 2 pasos:

1. Declararla: Siendo en este paso cuando tu programa ***reserva*** un espacio en la memoria ram, para luego poder *almacenar* datos en ella(teniendo en cuenta el tipo de variable que hayas declarado). Ej: `int a;`, `bool b;`, `Object c;`
2. Inicializarla: Ya con el lugar reservado, podes guardar tus datos en tal lugar, para luego usarlos. Ej:`a = 2;`,`b = true`, `c = new String[10]`

En tu caso quieres usar un array de `String`, por lo tanto y con cualquier variable, luego de declarar tu variable, tenes que inicializarla.

```
String mensaje[]; //Declaro 

mensaje = new String[10];//Inicializo

public static String[] mensaje = new String[10];//Todo en una línea.
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sale el `NullPointerException` por que nunca inicializas el variable `mensaje`. En términos simples, creaste un espacio en la memoria para la el array pero nunca lo llenaste con el array en si. La solución fácil es cambiar esta linea:

```
public static String[] mensaje = new String[10];
```

donde `10` es el numero de lugares que quieres que tenga tu array (lo puedes cambiar al numero que quieras). Toma en cuenta que los `Arrays` tienen un tamaño predeterminado (cuando inicializas un array con un tamaño, no lo puedes hacer mas grande ni mas chico). Si quieres un array con un tamaño dinámico, te sugiero un [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

En java estas dos lineas son equivalentes:

```
public static String[] mensaje;
```

y

```
public static String[] mensaje = null;
```

Y al atributo (de clase) "mensaje" nunca se le dio otro valor distinto a null, y por eso tiene el null que levanta al final dicha excepcion al intentar usarlo.

Comment: Es cierto que en ambos casos el valor de `mensaje` queda a `null`, pero no es 100% cierto decir que ambas sentencias son equivalentes, porque en un caso, la variable está inicializada, y en el otro no, y para el compilador, esa es una distinción importante.